# parted mkpart is fs-type required

Tags: parted

I am running this line:
`parted -s ${drive} -- mklabel msdos \
    mkpart primary 0% 100%`

and then formatting with vfat but my question is do i need to specify `fs-type` if just making it msdos ?

Comment: The question title is misleading. You can indeed say `parted $disk  mkpart $label $FSTYPE`, and I was hoping to find an answer covering whether or not the fstype has to be specified, and what are the consequences of specifying a different one from what the filesystem will be, e.g. `parted ... mkpart ... ext4` followed by `mkfs.xfs ...`. No matter, I think it's safest to omit the fstype in `parted`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mklabel` command specifies the type of partition **table**. The partition itself still needs to be formatted correctly.

Comment: thanks for that. i was trying to find this in the man pages but i just wanted to make sure.